# T-SQL, Select string between 4th and 5th comma

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to get the string between 5th and 6th comma, without using a function, because  I am selecting other columns as well, so using a function will not help me

This is the string value

```
"RBC,Dev,PROM0006581,T85230,P0263240,**Dev**,CHG0048754_DYN_DIF,Code changes as part of DYN -Tiered/Scaled & Bonus Interest for DIF Products
"
```

can someone please help me

Comment: what do you mean without using a function?

Comment: You can include scalar functions (which this would be) in select statements. The way to do it without a function would be a very, very, very long series of charindex statements.

Comment: charindex is still a function :)

Comment: This is really poor schema design.  Each of the fields in that data should be in it's own column.

Comment: the downvote saga begins as seeing it now

Answer (score 2):

You can do following:

```
DECLARE @Values VARCHAR(MAX) = 'RBC,Dev,PROM0006581,T85230,P0263240,**Dev**,CHG0048754_DYN_DIF,Code changes as part of DYN -Tiered/Scaled & Bonus Interest for DIF Products'

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Values') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Values;
CREATE TABLE #Values (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),Item  VARCHAR(100));

DECLARE @Insert VARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO #Values VALUES ('''+REPLACE(@Values,',','''),(''')+''');';
EXEC (@Insert);

SELECT * FROM #Values
```

Resulting:

[image]

And

```
SELECT Item FROM #Values WHERE ID=5
```

Resulting

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should get you what you're looking for...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #testData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    String VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
    );

INSERT #TestData (String) VALUES ('RBC,Dev,PROM0006581,T85230,P0263240,**Dev**,CHG0048754_DYN_DIF,Code changes as part of DYN -Tiered/Scaled & Bonus Interest for DIF Product');

SELECT *,
    RequestedValue = SUBSTRING(td.String, c4.Comma + 1, ISNULL(c5.Comma - c4.Comma - 1, 1000))
FROM
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', td.String, 1), 0)) ) c1 (Comma)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', td.String, c1.Comma + 1), 0)) ) c2 (Comma)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', td.String, c2.Comma + 1), 0)) ) c3 (Comma)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', td.String, c3.Comma + 1), 0)) ) c4 (Comma)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', td.String, c4.Comma + 1), 0)) ) c5 (Comma);
```

HTH, Jason

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple in-line and XML Safe approach (not just &'s).

Grabbing the 5th value. Not 100% sure if this needs to be adjusted up or down

**Sample Data**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeColumn varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'RBC,Dev,PROM0006581,T85230,P0263240,**Dev**,CHG0048754_DYN_DIF,Code changes as part of DYN -Tiered/Scaled & Bonus Interest for DIF Products')
```

**The Query**

```
Select ID
      ,SomeValue = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(SomeColumn,',','|||') as [*] For XML Path('')),'|||','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.').value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
ID  SomeValue
1   P0263240
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one solution that involve replacing comma `,` with xml tags and thereby converting column into an XML datatype.
Below query will give you 6th item (i.e between 5th and 6th comma as you want)

```
select * 
      , Column2 = convert(XML,'<s>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(MyColumn,'&','&amp;'),',','</s><s>') + '</s>').value('/s[6]','varchar(200)')
FROM [dbo].[Table1]
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ef043/1)

But you have to escape any reserved XML character in your data by replacing it with entity references otherwise XML cast will fail. like `&` is replaced with `&amp` in the above query

[XML reserved character on Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145315(v=sql.90).aspx)

**Updated Query**

As @John mentioned in his answer `FOR XML Path` is a neat and elegant way to escape special XML characters.So my updated query would be.

```
SELECT * 
      , Column2 = convert(XML,'<s>' + REPLACE((SELECT ISNULL(MyColumn,'') FOR XML Path('')),',','</s><s>') + '</s>').value('/s[6]','varchar(200)')
FROM [dbo].[Table1]
```

Comment: I have explained it as much as I could in my answer.You should break down the query into steps and try to understand what it is doing. I have created a sql fiddle where I break down the query into steps.(shown as columns) see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ef043/4

Comment: if i need values between the 1st and 4th element based on this query is it possible to acheive?

Answer (score 0):

Write a table-valued function that accepts the string and a delimiter character as parameters and returns the parsed elements of the string and the element's position as a two-column table.  You can then JOIN to an invocation of that function, which SQL will treat just like a table, so if you want the text between the 5th and 6th comma then you'd put "and position = 6" in the JOIN clause.

Comment: but this goes directly against the `without using a function` requirement from op

Comment: It is, however, completely compatible with the stated goal of "selecting other columns as well".  Using a function here will not prevent the OP from doing that.

Comment: I agree with your comment but how to join back?

Comment: I write a function that gives me two columns but to join back will not be possible, can you please elaborate

Comment: Sure.  Once you have your table-valued function (I'll call the columns "Element" and "Position" for this example), you add this element to your SELECT list: (SELECT Element from My_String_Splitter_Function(Field_With_List) where Position = 6) as Element_Between_Comma_5_and_6

So I actually misspoke earlier, as this is a sub-select rather than a join.  My apologies.

Comment: If you shared more details about your query, the tables you're using, etc., I'd be able to be more specific.

Comment: brian,@string = /branches/feature_P0265698-13_2017_FundServ_Enhancement/mfs_base/rep/CLCNRPT01       i need to get the string until the 3rd '/', sorry for the late reply, only now is aw your comment

Comment: Okay, so you'd call your table-valued function, passing that string and '/' in as parameters, and the results will be a single-column table with five records, each record containing one element of the path.  If you need the first three, you'd just re-concatenate the first three records with whatever delimiter you want in between the elements.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Don't forget to mark this as the solution - that will help others find this solution.